# Select with just added property

Tags: c#, linq, select, .net-core

I've got problem with reference to `languageId` I've just created in `Select`. I know it can't be done in this way, because `m.` in `m.languageId` is not that i want.

```
 var problem = await DataContext.ShopsProducts
                .Select(m => new
                {
                    languageId = m.Shop.LanguageId,
                    name = m.Product.LocalizedProductDetails.Select(
                        n => n.LanguageId == **m.languageId**);
```

I know I can replace `m.languageId` as `m.Shop.LanguageId`, but this is pretty longer in my project and there are more references in that `Select` to it. Is there any way for that, or should I take this out from Db before whole query?

Comment: Not clear what you want to achieve? What problem you are facing? What error if any?

Comment: It is 5 extra characters, it is the right way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't reference other created fields in the initializer of an a type. The only way to do what you want is to do an intermediate projection, but then you add another layer on top of your original projection:

```
var problem = await DataContext.ShopsProducts
            .Select(m => new
            {
                languageId = m.Shop.LanguageId,
                m = m
            })
            .Select(m => new
            {
                m.languageId,
                name = m.m.Product.LocalizedProductDetails.Select(
                    n => n.LanguageId == m.languageId);
            })
```

which may be "uglier" that the original.

Comment: If you are bothering to do the projection, why not replace the other reference to `m.Shop.LanguageId` with `m.languageId` (in which case you also don't need the field name since it will be inferred) ?